# What is the difference between sending tokens to liquidity pool and to contract address?

Tags: contract-development, bsc, liquidity-provider

Let's assume I create a token XYZ with a total supply of 1 million unit.

I send 500 000 tokens to the token address - e.g: 0xD5A7448b2289d24432F4F2F714458efA8a996359.
I add 100 000 tokens to the liquidity pool on Pancake swap to give the token a value?

Someone buys 10000 units of my token - where is that deducted from?
Is there a way to check token balance on the contract address?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldnt send tokens to the token contract address. Unless you have a specific function implemented to recover them, they'll be lost forever. @zmy is right, but a better way to check for the balance of a pair is to call getReserves for this pair contract. that'll give you the amount of tokenA and tokenB stored in that contract (the liquidity available) from there you can calculate the price of the token or do whatever you want.

Comment: BTW you shouldnt send tokens directly to the pair address using the `transfer` function from the token contract either, UniswapV2Router has an addLiquidity function that does that.

Answer (score 0):

If someone buys the token, it will be deducted from Pancake: 100,000-1000

Check the balanceOf a specified token held at any address: balanceOf()